# Facebook login with read and publish permission in android facebook SDK 4.8.0

Tags: android, facebook

Integrated Facebook login in my android application. 
I have two requirement in my application
1) Getting logged user email id 
2) Post a feed to user Facebook wall about the app installation and link

I can able to get email by using read permissions

```
private void fbLogin() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,
            Arrays.asList(
                    "public_profile",
                    "user_birthday",
                    "email"
            )
    );
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = facebookPreferences.edit();
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            if (accessToken != null) {
                fbProfile();
            }
        }
}
```

I can able to post the feed by using publish permissions

```
private void fbLogin() {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,
            Arrays.asList(
                    "publish_actions"
            )
    );
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = facebookPreferences.edit();
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            if (accessToken != null) {
                fbPostAFeed();
            }
        }
}
```

Without login again to change the permission.
But my requirement is get email id and post a feed to Facebook.
I know login can be associated with either read permissions or publish permissions.
I searched about this found one thing is Session but, 
Facebook doc say: Session class is no longer available in the most recent version of the SDK
Then how can I perform this. Is their any way to do so.
Thanks in advance ..

Comment: what exactly do you want to post? sounds like you want to autopost to the user profile, with the information that he installed the app?

Comment: You are not allowed to post automatically, or specify the message of a post for the user.

Comment: @ luschn Thank for your replay.. Exactly what i wanted is auto posting to the user profile.

Comment: @ CBroe Thank for your replay.. Ok I just wanted to try If possible..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some permissions and add below code fr sharing feeds, below code contains images too. You can customize it as per your need.

```html
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

  manager = LoginManager.getInstance();

  manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

  manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
      publishImage();

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancel() {
      System.out.println("onCancel");
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
      System.out.println("onError");
     }
    });

 }


    private void publishImage() {
  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    //You need to get bitmap from any source.

  SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
    .build();

  SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();

  ShareApi.share(content, null);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }
```